# Cleaning my json data so I can make a chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, charts

Hello I was able to use this API to get data, but now I need to make it into a chart in my react project. I am new to JS and react so i am having trouble making a chart with this data json. I wanted to show the prices by bedrooms plotted against time but the format of the json sucks for this. What's a good chart component to use? Also, I have the json retrieved. That is fine, displaying it is what I'm having difficulty doing.

Here is the format of the JSON:

````
{"id":"10012","zipCode":"10012","rentalData":{"averageRent":5033,"minRent":1500,"maxRent":10000,"totalRentals":422,"detailed":[{"bedrooms":1,"averageRent":4412,"minRent":1900,"maxRent":10000,"totalRentals":257},{"bedrooms":2,"averageRent":5640,"minRent":1500,"maxRent":10000,"totalRentals":122},{"bedrooms":3,"averageRent":6709,"minRent":3595,"maxRent":10000,"totalRentals":38},{"bedrooms":4,"averageRent":8997,"minRent":7995,"maxRent":9995,"totalRentals":3},{"bedrooms":5,"averageRent":10000,"minRent":10000,"maxRent":10000,"totalRentals":2}],"history":{"2020-04":{"averageRent":22277.53,"minRent":1600,"maxRent":80000,"totalRentals":814,"detailed":[{"bedrooms":0,"averageRent":3342.45,"minRent":1600,"maxRent":30000,"totalRentals":123},{"bedrooms":1,"averageRent":3836.1,"minRent":2170,"maxRent":44894,"totalRentals":315},{"bedrooms":2,"averageRent":6692.21,"minRent":2595,"maxRent":40000,"totalRentals":256},{"bedrooms":3,"averageRent":9467.1,"minRent":3595,"maxRent":30000,"totalRentals":96},{"bedrooms":4,"averageRent":16004.08,"minRent":4995,"maxRent":49900,"totalRentals":12},{"bedrooms":5,"averageRent":22333.33,"minRent":7500,"maxRent":35000,"totalRentals":6},{"bedrooms":6,"averageRent":77500,"minRent":75000,"maxRent":80000,"totalRentals":2},{"bedrooms":7,"averageRent":65000,"minRent":65000,"maxRent":65000,"totalRentals":2},{"bedrooms":140,"averageRent":14000,"minRent":14000,"maxRent":14000,"totalRentals":1},{"bedrooms":460,"averageRent":4600,"minRent":4600,"maxRent":4600,"totalRentals":1}]},"2020-05":{"averageRent":24452.75,"minRent":1600,"maxRent":80000,"totalRentals":789,"detailed":[{"bedrooms":0,"averageRent":4245.28,"minRent":1600,"maxRent":44894,"totalRentals":137},{"bedrooms":1,"averageRent":3891.14,"minRent":2300,"maxRent":44894,"totalRentals":284},{"bedrooms":2,"averageRent":7296.89,"minRent":2595,"maxRent":40000,"totalRentals":246},{"bedrooms":3,"averageRent":9765.93,"minRent":3595,"maxRent":40000,"totalRentals":102},{"bedrooms":4,"averageRent":16542.22,"minRent":5100,"maxRent":49900,"totalRentals":9},{"bedrooms":5,"averageRent":21833.33,"minRent":6500,"maxRent":35000,"totalRentals":6},{"bedrooms":6,"averageRent":77500,"minRent":75000,"maxRent":80000,"totalRentals":2},{"bedrooms":7,"averageRent":65000,"minRent":65000,"maxRent":65000,"totalRentals":2},{"bedrooms":140,"averageRent":14000,"minRent":14000,"maxRent":14000,"totalRentals":1}]},...```

'''
Up until this month of this year
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your JSON to JS. There’s a few ways to do this depending on how you’re getting the JSON string, but for example:

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Then you need to transform your data, but the exact output you want will depend on what chart plug-in you’re using ([Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/line.html) is popular) and exactly what you want to show (by zip code? Average rental? Bedrooms?).

There’s a syntax error in your sample data, but you’ll need to iterate over the `parsedData.rentalData.history`, for example using [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am new to this and this was a huge help!